# Insert text from the card into the modal window

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in js

there is a question
I have a slider of 6 slides in which the feedback cards,
when I click on the "read in full" button, I need to enter this review into the modal window
, to be more precise, I need to get data from the block on which the event occurred and insert it into the modal

```js
let reviewsbtn = document.querySelectorAll(".reviews_link")
let reviewswindow = document.querySelector("#reviews_window")
let reviewsbox = document.querySelector("#reviews_wrap")
let closeButtonReviews = document.getElementById("closeButtonreviews");
let results

for (results of reviewsbtn) {
  results.addEventListener("click", openReviwes)

}

function openReviwes(event) {
  reviewswindow.classList.add("reviews_window")
  reviewsbox.classList.add("reviews_wrap")
}

closeButtonReviews.addEventListener("click", closebox)

function closebox() {
  reviewswindow.classList.remove("reviews_window")
  reviewsbox.classList.remove("reviews_wrap")
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <div class="reviews_box">
    <div class="reviews_name">
      <img src="img/A.svg" alt="Reviews">
      <p class="reviews__name">Гоар</p>
    </div>
    <p class="reviews_text">.....</p>
    <button type="button" id="reviews_buttons5" class="reviews_link">read in full</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="reviews_window">
  <div id="reviews_wrap">
    <div class="reviews_name">
      <img src="img/d-reviews.svg" alt="Reviews">
      <p>Jonh</p>
    </div>
    <p>...</p>
    <button type="button" id="closeButtonreviews" class="reviews_close"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand how to do it better

Comment: What data from the block are we talking about. Your example could be a little more complete, see [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the correct elements with `document.querySelector` on the parent of the button.

```js
function openReviwes(event) {
    // ...
    reviewsbox.querySelector('#reviews_wrap > p').textContent = 
       event.target.parentElement.querySelector('.reviews_text').textContent;
}
```